# Norm of an element as a determinant

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I know that some books show the norm of an element in a number field, as the determinant of a matrix associated to a specific linear transformation, but some other books don't show this definition, other books show the definition as the product of all embeddings of the element.

I have been trying to show that the determinant equals to the product of the embeddings, but I'm having trouble finding the associated matrix for the linear transformation $T(x) = \alpha x$, and doing some research seems like the matrix is the companion matrix, and if that is the case I really don't see how that is the matrix and how to calculate the determinant of that matrix.

Can you help me solving those things please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/tracenorm.pdf for norm as determinant of linear map "multiply by this element",  Theorem 1.1 of http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/tracenorm2.pdf for identification of this norm with product over images under the Galois group for a Galois extension of fields, and proof of Theorem 3.3 in http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/154Page/handouts/normtrace.pdf for a proof that the norm is also a product over field embeddings.  But read carefully: you must take a product with multiplicities if the extn. is not separable.